# stuck at media query, i can’t fix it

Tags: html, css, media-queries, responsive

https://codepen.io/rofy123/pen/pobYJxB

hello everyone,
I have been developing this website and i am a new developer. While developing this website i didn’t face any problem until media query. i was trying to add media query at nav bar, i want to hide the main-nav bar when media query use. but i can’t seems fix it, i am stuck at media query. I need some help here, it would be grate. i have provided my whole code through codepen link.
thank you

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Inkpot To The Grave-Salafi Bookstore</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora|Ubuntu:300,400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="manu-btn">
            <i class="fas fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="container-1">
            <!-- Nav -->
            <nav class="main-nav main-nav-color">
                <a href="#"><img class="logo" src="images/logo/logo-inkpot-11.1.png" alt="Inkpot To The Grave"></a>
                <ul class="main-manu show">
                    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CATEGORIES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="right-manu">
                    <li><i class="fas fa-user"></i></li>
                    <li><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>


    <!-- Home cards 1 -->
    <div class="container-2">
        <h2>Recent Arrivals</h2>
        <section class="home-cards">
            <div class="products">
                <a href="#"><img class="product-image" src="images/books/1.Fiqh of Fasting Workbook.jpg"
                        alt="Fiqh of Fasting Workbook"></a>
                <h3><a class="product-title br-line" href="#">Fiqh of Fasting Workbook</a></h3>
                <p class="price">£19.99</p>
                <button class="button btn btn-danger" type="button">add basket</button>
            </div>
            <div class="products">
                <a href="#"><img class="product-image" src="images/books/1.Fiqh of Fasting Workbook.jpg"
                        alt="Fiqh of Fasting Workbook"></a>
                <h3><a class="product-title br-line" href="#">Fiqh of Fasting Workbook</a></h3>
                <p class="price">£19.99</p>
                <button class="button btn btn-danger" type="button">add basket</button>
            </div>
            <div class="products">
                <a href="#"><img class="product-image" src="images/books/1.Fiqh of Fasting Workbook.jpg"
                        alt="Fiqh of Fasting Workbook"></a>
                <h3><a class="product-title br-line" href="#">Fiqh of Fasting Workbook</a></h3>
                <p class="price">£19.99</p>
                <button class="button btn btn-danger" type="button">add basket</button>
            </div>
            <div class="products">
                <a href="#"><img class="product-image" src="images/books/1.Fiqh of Fasting Workbook.jpg"
                        alt="Fiqh of Fasting Workbook"></a>
                <h3><a class="product-title br-line" href="#">Fiqh of Fasting Workbook</a></h3>
                <p class="price">£19.99</p>
                <button class="button btn btn-danger" type="button">add basket</button>
            </div>
            <div class="products">
                <a href="#"><img class="product-image" src="images/books/1.Fiqh of Fasting Workbook.jpg"
                        alt="Fiqh of Fasting Workbook"></a>
                <h3><a class="product-title br-line" href="#">Fiqh of Fasting Workbook</a></h3>
                <p class="price">£19.99</p>
                <button class="button btn btn-danger" type="button">add basket</button>
            </div>
            <div class="products">
                <a href="#"><img class="product-image" src="images/books/1.Fiqh of Fasting Workbook.jpg"
                        alt="Fiqh of Fasting Workbook"></a>
                <h3><a class="product-title br-line" href="#">Fiqh of Fasting Workbook</a></h3>
                <p class="price">£19.99</p>
                <button class="button btn btn-danger" type="button">add basket</button>
            </div>
            <div class="products">
                <a href="#"><img class="product-image" src="images/books/1.Fiqh of Fasting Workbook.jpg"
                        alt="Fiqh of Fasting Workbook"></a>
                <h3><a class="product-title br-line" href="#">Fiqh of Fasting Workbook</a></h3>
                <p class="price">£19.99</p>
                <button class="button btn btn-danger" type="button">add basket</button>
            </div>
            <div class="products">
                <a href="#"><img class="product-image" src="images/books/1.Fiqh of Fasting Workbook.jpg"
                        alt="Fiqh of Fasting Workbook"></a>
                <h3><a class="product-title br-line" href="#">Fiqh of Fasting Workbook</a></h3>
                <p class="price">£19.99</p>
                <button class="button btn btn-danger" type="button">add basket</button>
            </div>
        
        </section>
    </div>


  

</body>

</html>
```

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Lora, serif';
}

header {
    background: #eee7d6;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.container-1{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 40px 0;
}

/* Nav */
.main-nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 20px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.main-nav .logo {
    width: 100px;
}

.main-nav ul {
    display: flex;
}

.main-nav ul li {
    padding:  0 10px;
}

.main-nav ul li a {
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    color: #000000;
}

.main-nav ul li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #e0ad37;
}

.main-nav ul.main-manu {
    flex: 1;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

>.manu-btn {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 54px;
    right: 30px;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
}

/* Home cards */

.container-2 {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
.home-cards {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.products {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 48px;
    text-align: center;
}

.product-image {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.product-image:hover,
.product-image:focus {
    opacity: 0.75;
}

.product-title {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-align: center;
}

.product-title:hover,
.product-title:focus {
    color: #e0ad37;
}

.price {
    font-size: o.6667rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #707070;
    margin-bottom: 1em 0;
}

.button {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: .80rem;
    background-color: #eee7d6;
    padding: .75em 2em;
    margin: 1em;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Lora, serif';
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.btn {
    background-color: white; 
    color: #707070;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.btn:hover,
.btn:focus {
    background-color: #e0ad37;
    color: white;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
    .container-1 {
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
    
    .manu-btn {
        display: block;
    }
    
    .manu-btn:hover {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    
    .main-nav ul.right-menu {
        padding-right: 100px;
    }
    
    .main-nav ul.main-menu {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        left: 0;
        background: #f2f2f2;
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        border-right: #ccc 1px solid;
        opacity: 0.9;
        padding: 30px;
        transform: translateX(-500px);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
      
    .main-nav ul.main-menu li {
        padding: 10px;
        border-bottom: #ccc solid 1px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    
    .main-nav ul.main-menu li:last-child {
        border-bottom: 0;
    }
    
    .main-nav ul.main-manu.show {
        transform: translateX(-20px);
    }
    
    .right-manu{
        padding-right: 100px;
    }
    .products {
        width: 300px;
    }
    
    .product-image {
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
    }

    .product-title,
    .price,
    .button {
        font-size: 1rem;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .manu-btn {
        display: block;
    }
    
    .products {
        width: 150px;
    }
    
    .product-image {
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
    }

    .product-title,
    .price,
    .button {
        font-size: .50rem;
    }
}
```

Comment: in the media query, you can add 
.main-nav{
 display: none;
}

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to hide your nav-bar with `display: none` in your media queries. Remember to change it back once your hamburger menu is clicked with Javascript.

In your media queries:

```css
@media (max-width: 700px) {
.container-1 {
    display: none;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: yes....display: none; it was a mistake, i can fix it easily by display block. that wasn’t the main problem, the main problem was these css code....class name with ".main-nav ul.main-menu". if you check this class then you will see those code not behaving as i want to behave. and thank you for your reply.